# Magento 2: Custom module to show the available downloads

Tags: magento2, module, api, rest-api

I am working on a requirement to develop a module which will have a REST api to get the number of remaining downloads for a given Order id 'increment_id' and Item id 'item_id'.

As a first step, I created a basic folder structure under app\code\Custom

```
-ManageDownloadCounter
  -etc
    -webapi_rest
    -module.xml
  -composer.json
  -registration.php
```

I do Joomla development and started learning Magento2 module development.  Need some advice on what is the next step?  Are there any examples available in GitHub related to my requirement?

Answer (score 0):

You could find the official documentation in:

http://devdocs.magento.com/

And some official examples [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples)

You can find a lot more googling